# External content type: bdc identity

Tags: 2013, list, content-type, external-content-type, bdc

I have a list with an external content type.

For 3 items, I have the same bdc identity.

How is it possible? Is not bdc identity suppose to be unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns defined as unique (so the BDC identity was built on that colums) were not unique in the sql view, that why I had not unique BDCIdentity.